# How to custom GtkScale shape (C program) to obtain sliders like in the "level" window of GIMP

Tags: css, c, gtk

I have a question about GtkScale shape.

Indeed I want my Gtkscale looks like in level window of Gimp.
I mean:

- a bar
- 3 triangles (here there are one for shadows, one for midtones, one for highlights)
  [image: Sliders in gimp]

I can build the shade bar with GtkLabel and CSS file:

```
.label-shade {
background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                            left top, right top,
                            from (black),
                            to (shade (white, 0.95)));
}
```

But I don't know how I can build triangle sliders.

Comment: Are those three triangles independently moveable? If so, GtkScale isn't the right tool for the job; it only supports one such triangle. You'll need to implement the widget yourself, which is probably what GIMP is already doing.

Comment: It seems that they drawn their own widget, you're right :-(. That's such a pain doing that.

Comment: It's not always very difficult to draw your own widget. That would be a rather simple one to implement.

Comment: Yes maybe. But I never done this before :).

Answer (score 1):

For a quick&dirty implementation, you can leverage 3 nested `GtkPaned` to simulate that behavior:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="wide_handle">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkPaned">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="position">10</property>
                <property name="wide_handle">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="resize">True</property>
                    <property name="shrink">True</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkOverlay" id="Overlay1">
                    <property name="width_request">48</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="width_request">24</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="halign">end</property>
                        <property name="stock">gtk-go-forward</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="index">-1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child type="overlay">
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="width_request">24</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="halign">start</property>
                        <property name="stock">gtk-goto-first</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="resize">True</property>
                    <property name="shrink">False</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">True</property>
                <property name="shrink">False</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkPaned">
                <property name="width_request">48</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="wide_handle">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkOverlay" id="Overlay2">
                    <property name="width_request">48</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="width_request">24</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="halign">end</property>
                        <property name="stock">gtk-goto-last</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="index">-1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child type="overlay">
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="width_request">24</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="halign">start</property>
                        <property name="stock">gtk-go-back</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="resize">True</property>
                    <property name="shrink">False</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="resize">True</property>
                    <property name="shrink">True</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">True</property>
                <property name="shrink">False</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```